# Vue 3 with Vuex 4

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I'm using Vue 3 with the composition API and trying to understand how I can map my state from Vuex directly so the template can use it and update it on the fly with the v-model.

Does `mapState` works or something else to solve this issue? Right no I need to get my state by a getter, print it out in the template, and then do a manual commit for each field in my state... In Vue 2 with Vuex, I had this 100% dynamic

Comment: please share the code

Answer (score 2):

To make two-way binding between your input and store `state`  you could use a writable computed property using set/get methods :

```
setup(){
  const store=useStore()

   const username=computed({
       get:()=>store.getters.getUsername,
       set:(newVal)=>store.dispatch('changeUsername',newVal)
    })

return {username}
}
```

template :

```
<input v-model="username" />
```

Comment: I see what you mean, is this the only way? Let say that you have like 10-15 fields, then you need to make one computed for each field, I hoped that Vuex had something that auto-mapped this for you

Comment: @nahoj Afaik this is planned for Vuex 5. Currently you can settle with your own helper function that suits your needs

Comment: I see.. Do you have any examples for a helper function like this?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim It's a general question, not a code-specific one. I know that you can use, getter and setter.. I was looking for a dynamic map function.

Comment: If you could give an example that would helpful

Comment: Well, just think of 2-way bindings for Vuex that don't require you to map each state individually with getters and setters instead use a helper function that will take care of this for you based on which fields/states you give it.

In previous versions, I had a helper function called `...mapFields()`.. I need one for Vuex 4/Vue 3

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it!

Helper function:

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { computed } from 'vue'

const useMapFields = (namespace, options) => {
const store = useStore()    
const object = {}

if (!namespace) {
    console.error('Please pass the namespace for your store.')
}

for (let x = 0; x < options.fields.length; x++) {
    const field = [options.fields[x]]
    
    object[field] = computed({
        get() {
            return store.state[namespace][options.base][field]
        },
        set(value) {
            store.commit(options.mutation, { [field]: value })
        }
    })
}


return object
}

export default useMapFields
```

And in setup()

```
       const {FIELD1, FIELD2}  = useMapFields('MODULE_NAME', {
            fields: [
                'FIELD1',
                 etc…
            ],
            base: 'form', // Deep as next level state.form
            mutation: 'ModuleName/YOUR_COMMIT'
        })
```

Vuex Mutation:

```
    MUTATION(state, obj) {
        const key = Object.keys(obj)[0]
        state.form[key] = obj[key]
    }
```